# RollingFileAppender implementation while migrating from Log4j to Log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

The following method was being used for a while now when the system I am currently working on has Log4j. Now that we are moving from Log4j to Log4j2, I am getting compilation issues with it.

```java
private void initLogger(String logFile) {
    RollingFileAppender fileAppender = (RollingFileAppender) Logger.getRootLogger()
        .getAppender("FILE");

    if (logFile!=null && !"".equals(logFile)) {
        if (null != fileAppender) {
            fileAppender.setFile(logFile);
            fileAppender.activateOptions();
            fileAppender.setImmediateFlush(true);
        }
    } 
}
```

Log4j2 jars: log4j-api-2.12.1.jar, log4j-core-2.12.1.jar

Can someone provide please help with what might be the right approach to deal with the above method?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `xml` configuration like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName=".\logs\app.log"
                     filePattern=".\logs\$${date:yyyy-MM}\app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If you want to use properties, YAML, JSON without xml than follow this [Link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) and read steps from 1 to 10 at `Automatic Configuration`